# Enable viewPager single click inside listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

I am using view pager inside listview for swiping multiple images. Swipe are working fine but single click on view pager are disabled because i have used another image layout for showing image in view pager.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following attribute in the parent layout of your list item:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: Yes , you are right but I have use this and i will get the Listview Item focusability but my viewpager itemclick is not working.